# How do I know when an interface is directly implemented in a type ignoring inherited ones?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

The issue appears is when I have a class implementing an interface, and extending a class which implements an interface:

```
class Some : SomeBase, ISome {}
class SomeBase : ISomeBase {}
interface ISome{}
interface ISomeBase{}
```

Since typeof(Some).GetInterfaces() returns and array with ISome and ISomeBase, i'm not able to distinguish if ISome is implemented or inherited (as ISomeBase). As MSDN I can't assume the order of the interfaces in the array, hence I'm lost. The method typeof(Some).GetInterfaceMap() does not distinguish them either.

Comment: Why do you care? What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's long to explain, but I want to automatically register services in AutoFac based on their interface implementation, since the services can be extended, I need the distinction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to exclude the interfaces implemented by the base type :

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfaces(this Type type, bool includeInherited)
    {
        if (includeInherited || type.BaseType == null)
            return type.GetInterfaces();
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces().Except(type.BaseType.GetInterfaces());
    }
}

...


foreach(Type ifc in typeof(Some).GetInterfaces(false))
{
    Console.WriteLine(ifc);
}
```