# Get only direct interface instead of all?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class like the below. GetInterfaces() says

> If the current Type represents a type
>   parameter in the definition of a
>   generic type or generic method, this
>   method searches the interface
>   constraints and any interfaces
>   inherited from class or interface
>   constraints.

Is it possible for me to not get any inherited interface? When i use GetInterfaces on ABC i only want to see DEF, not DEF and GHI.

```
interface DEF : GHI {...}
class ABC : DEF {...}
```

Comment: Since I`m only on my iPad I can`t test code or look up all the methods, but here`s a thought. Could you find all the interfaces your type implements (including inherites ones), then move on to the base type of your type, find all the interfaces *that* type implements, and subtract those from the first set? I would think you would be left with what ABC itself added of interfaces. If anyone wants to "steal" this comment and type up a real answer of it, please do, it won`t be until tomorrow until I`m back at my computer.

Comment: the GetInterfaces() is a method on the Type class.

Comment: Ah, my apologies, your "base type" is an interface, then I don`t know.

Comment: @Lasse: I've understood the problem differently; I think the OP is only interested in interface-hierarchies.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Firstly, the MSDN snippet you've posted doesn't have anything to do with your actual question. It deals with when you have, for example, a generic type such as `class Foo<T> where T : IEnumerable`, and you try calling `GetInterfaces` on the type-parameter `T`,  for example through `typeof(Foo<>).GetGenericArguments().Single().GetInterfaces().`

Secondly, the problem is slightly ill-specified. Note that when a class implements an interface, it must implement *all* of the interfaces 'inherited' by that interface. It's simply a C# convenience feature that lets you omit the inherited interfaces in the class-declaration. In your example, it's perfectly legal (and no different) to *explicitly* include the 'inherited' `GHI` interface:

```
class ABC : DEF, GHI {...}
```

---

I've assumed that what you really want to do is find a 'minimal set' of interfaces that 'covers' all of the type's implemented interfaces. This results in a slightly  simplified version of the [Set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Here's one way to solve it, without any attempt whatsoever to be algorithmically efficient. The idea is to produce the minimal interface-set by filtering out those interfaces that are *already* implemented by *other* interfaces implemented by the type.

```
Type type = ...

var allInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();    
var minimalInterfaces = from iType in allInterfaces 
                        where !allInterfaces.Any(t => t.GetInterfaces()
                                                       .Contains(iType))
                        select iType;
```

(
**EDIT** -  Here's a better way of doing the above:

```
var minimalInterfaces = allInterfaces.Except
                        (allInterfaces.SelectMany(t => t.GetInterfaces()));
```

)

For example, for `List<int>`:

```
allInterfaces: 

System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.IEnumerable
System.Collections.IList
System.Collections.ICollection

minimalInterfaces:

System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.IList
```

---

Do note that this solution covers *interface* 'hierarchies' only (which is what you appear to want), not how they relate to the class's *class* hierarchy. In particular, it pays no attention to *where* in a class's hierarchy an interface was first implemented.

For example, let's say we have:

```
interface IFoo { }
interface IBar : IFoo { }
interface IBaz { } 

class Base : IBar {  }
class Derived : Base, IBaz {  }
```

Now if you try using the solution I've described to get the minimal interface-set for `Derived`, you would get `IBaz` as well as `IBar`. If you don't want `IBar`, you would have to go to more effort: eliminate interfaces implemented by base-classes. The easiest way to do this would be to remove from the minimal interface-set those interfaces implemented by the class's immediate base-class, as is mentioned in @MikeEast's answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is a nice piece from a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613867/how-do-i-know-when-an-interface-is-directly-implemented-in-a-type-ignoring-inheri):

```
public static class TypeExtensions {
   public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfaces(this Type type, bool includeInherited)
   {
      if (includeInherited || type.BaseType == null)
         return type.GetInterfaces();
      else
         return type.GetInterfaces().Except(type.BaseType.GetInterfaces());
   }
}
```

And usage:

```
foreach(Type ifc in typeof(Some).GetInterfaces(false)) {
   Console.WriteLine(ifc);
}
```

Comment: problem with this is it won't work for i.e. `IList<string>`, I had a similar solution based on @Lasse's comment

Comment: Ah, for the `BaseType` thing. Didn't see that one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, none of the posted solutions work for `typeof(C1)` and `typeof(I3)` in the example below.

I think the correct answer is that it is not possible to get the directly implemented interfaces using out-of-the-box framework calls.

```
private interface I1 { }

private interface I2 : I1 { }

private interface I3 : I2, I1 { }

public class C1 : I3, I1 { }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this for interface inheritance heirachy?

```
    public static Map GetTypeInheritance(Type type)
    {
        //get all the interfaces for this type
        var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();

        //get all the interfaces for the ancestor interfaces
        var baseInterfaces = interfaces.SelectMany(i => i.GetInterfaces());

        //filter based on only the direct interfaces
        var directInterfaces = interfaces.Where(i => baseInterfaces.All(b => b != i));

        Map map = new Map
            {
                Node = type,
                Ancestors = directInterfaces.Select(GetTypeInheritance).ToList()
            };

        return map;
    }

    public class Map
    {
       public Type Node { get; set; }
       public List<Map> Ancestors { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The same MSDN page says

> The GetInterfaces method does not
>   return interfaces in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or
>   declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which
>   interfaces are returned, because that
>   order varies.

So no, you can't skip interfaces.

Comment: The OP isn't trying to skip interfaces, but retrieve only the directly implemented interfaces.

Comment: I think the main problem here is that once a type implements an interface, there`s no concept of "directly implemented" any more. You`ll have to analyze the graph of interface "inheritance" and find the most plausible result.

Answer (score -1):

This question is duplicated both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1613867) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2055411).  In any case, here's my concise code that considers the points raised on this thread by @Ani and @Mikael:

```
var actualInterfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
foreach ( var result in actualInterfaces
    .Except( type.BaseType?.GetInterfaces() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Type>() ) //See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1613936
    .Except( actualInterfaces.SelectMany( i => i.GetInterfaces() ) ) //See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5318781
) yield return result;
```