# How to know if a class redefines an interface

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have the following classes :

```
internal class Father : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone() { ... }
    public void Dispose() { ... }
}

internal class Son : Father { }
internal class Daughter : Father, ICloneable { }
```

I tried to retrieve interfaces using GetInterfaces method from Type with reflection but there is no difference between Son and Daughter. Is there a way to find interfaces only declared at the current class level.

**For Son, the result should be nothing and for Daughter, it should be ICloneable.**

PS : I know it is useless to redefine an interface in a sub-class, but this does not come from my assembly...

Comment: `I know it is useless to redefine an interface in a sub-class`.  It's not actually, in the general case.  Here of course it is useless.  If either subclass had a `Clone` method though then it would make a huge difference.

Comment: Probably example is pretty _fake_ anyway if I understood your question you can check implemented interfaces (`GetInterfaces()`) and (for each method) which type is implementing that (`GetInterfaceMap()`).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti No, you can't.  In the example here `Son` and `Daughter` both implement the interface, both have a suitable method, and neither explicitly defines the method implementing the interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get only direct interface instead of all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318685/get-only-direct-interface-instead-of-all)

Comment: @Servy if he needs **only** to know if one interface is declared in Derived or not then he can do it (just checking DeclaringType of TargetMethods in interface map). If method names match but Derived doesn't (re)implement that interface then he won't see Derived as DeclaringType for ICloneable.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti If that can successfully distinguish between the two classes shown in the example then post it as an answer.

Comment: @Servy I still didn't understand for sure what OP wants...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Can you create a method that when given `Son` and `ICloneable` returns `false` but when given `Daughter` and `ICloneable` returns `true`?

Comment: @Servy yes, try: `instance.GetType().GetInterfaceMap(typeof(ICloneable))` to get mapping between methods and interfaces. Now pick first (`ICloneable` has just one method) `MethodInfo` in `TargetMethods` and read `DeclaringType`. For `Daughter` it'll be the same as `instance.GetType()` but for `Son` it'll be base type then you have a `true`/`false` result. Of course for `ICloneable` it's easier because it has just one method. Again **if** that's what OP wants.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti That was a rhetorical question.  My point was if you can create a method that does that, then, based on my interpretation, you correctly understand the question.  Based on the bolded line, this seems like a pretty sensible interpretation.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `typeof(Daughter).GetInterfaceMap(typeof(ICloneable)).TargetMethods[0].DeclaringType` returns `typeof(Father)` for me.

Comment: @Servy oh :| :| I posted that as answer, sorry...it's monday...

Comment: @svick I posted an answer with code tests, do you get same results?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [unmanaged .NET Metadata API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404384(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the managed Reflection API. [This blog post explains the differences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/08/06/reflection-vs-metadata.aspx). Specifically, the [`EnumInterfaceImpls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms232502(v=vs.110).aspx) method gives you what you want. I have not personally used the unmanaged API from managed code, but a quick look around SO gives you plenty of examples of people doing so. I hope this answers your question. I don't know what you're trying to achieve. If you need to implement some code practices policy checker, I think you're better off implementing it within the IDE (VS) via its code model API - your code can then reason about the C# source code, not the MSIL output. If you intend to use the interface as a marker interface that is "not inheritable", you're better off using attributes.