# Check closet inheritance of objects to declared type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, types

I am trying to choose the right way to select objects from a container when comparing types.
In the following example, There are 2 interfaces: ISomeInterface, ISomeSubInterface, where ISomeSubInterface inherites from ISomeInterface

There are also 2 classes: InterfaceClass, SubInterfaceClasswhere the names indicate the inherited interface.

Shortly: 
InterfaceClassis ISomeInterface

SubInterfaceClass is ISomeSubInterface is ISomeInterface

[image]

In the IsOfType method, I check for matching objects.

Current state: 
The method checks if the object in the container is of the declared type. When calling the method with ISomeInterface generic type, if both classes exist in the container, then both match as they both "are" ISomeInterface.

Wanted state:
The method will return the object(s) with the closest inheritance to ISomeInterface.

As the container saves the objects, and the runtime type is being compared, I understand why my current implementation fails.
My question would be, is it possible to implement such machanism that will return the wanted state?
I don't rule out changing the data structures or the way I add objects to that data structure.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _ = new Test();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private readonly List<ISomeInterface> _objects = new List<ISomeInterface>();

    public Test()
    {
        ISomeInterface obj1 = new InterfaceClass();
        ISomeInterface obj2 = new SubInterfaceClass();

        _objects.Add(obj1);
        _objects.Add(obj2);

        IEnumerable<ISomeSubInterface> retObjs1 = Get<ISomeSubInterface>();
        int count1 = retObjs1.Count(); // 1 As expected

        IEnumerable<ISomeInterface> retObjs2 = Get<ISomeInterface>();
        int count2 = retObjs2.Count(); // 2, wanted 1
    }

    private IEnumerable<T> Get<T>()
        where T : ISomeInterface
    {
        return _objects.Where(IsOfType<T>).Cast<T>();
    }

    private bool IsOfType<T>(ISomeInterface obj)
        where T : ISomeInterface
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType());
    }
}

internal class SubInterfaceClass: ISomeSubInterface { }
internal class InterfaceClass: ISomeInterface { }
internal interface ISomeSubInterface : ISomeInterface { }
internal interface ISomeInterface { }
```

Would appreciate help on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, btw.

Comment: Thanks, edited..

Comment: That's better. It was trivial but it's nice to have these things just copy, paste, and run. :-)

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318685/get-only-direct-interface-instead-of-all

Comment: @haim770 - It's close to a duplicate, but not exactly. That question shows how to build a query to answer this question, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: @Enigmativity, the core question here is the same: How do you differ between direct interface definitions and inherited ones. Once you modify `IsOfType()` to reflect that, the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the definition of "closest", this might not be a trivial task.

**Tried-N-True**

For now, let's focus on your example. I will conquer this from a different angle compared to @OguzOzgul's solution, but still use [`GetInterfaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces?view=netframework-4.8).

`GetInterfaces` **in your case** returns interface types in the same order as how those types are inherited:

```
SubInterfaceClass
0: ISomeSubInterface
1: ISomeInterface

InterfaceClass
0: ISomeInterface
```

As you could see, you could find the "closest" implementation type by finding the lowest possible index where `ISomeInterface` is at. And in your case, `ISomeInterface` sits at position 0 in the interface list of `InterfaceClass`, so you would select `InterfaceClass`.

This could be done via an aggregator:

```
private T GetClosetImplementationAsPerReflection<T>()
    where T : ISomeInterface
{
    var result = _objects.Where(IsOfType<T>)
        .Aggregate(
            // Default entry
            new { obj = default(T), rank = int.MaxValue },
            // Aggregator
            (currentEntry, o) =>
            {
                // Find all interface types implemented by the instance type
                // Because your class types do not have base type, the order of interfaces
                // appear in the list is same as how the interfaces are inherited.
                // e.g. 
                // SubInterfaceClass: 0->ISomeSubInterface, 1->ISomeInterface
                // InterfaceClass: 0->ISomeInterface
                var entryFound = o.GetType()
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Select((interfaceType, index) => new { interfaceType, index })
                .First(_ => _.interfaceType == typeof(T));

                // Now you could find the type / instance with ISomeInterface
                // at the lowest possible index
                if (entryFound.index < currentEntry.rank)
                {
                    return new { obj = (T)o, rank = entryFound.index };
                }
                else
                {
                    return currentEntry;
                }
            });


    return result.obj;
}
```

**However**

The above is a tried-n-true solution only to your trivial case. In reality, there is no such "closest" definition.

The compiler compiles `SubInterfaceClass` to this:

```
private class SubInterfaceClass : ISomeSubInterface, ISomeInterface
{
}
```

So `ISomeInterface` is arguably equally close to `SubInterfaceClass` compared to `InterfaceClass`. Though you could argue that when `ISomeInterface` appears after `ISomeSubInterface`, then `ISomeSubInterface` is closer, unfortunately the order is not visible to your code. [And it is not guaranteed by `GetInterfaces` method either](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces?view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

My suggestion is, define what "closest" means to you, and specifically implement logic for your own "closest".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by changing your `IsOfType<T>` method like this.

There can probably be better implementations of this linQ statement (more efficient maybe), but it should give what you need.

```
private bool IsOfType<T>(ISomeInterface obj)
    where T : ISomeInterface
{
    // The following statement does the following:
    // 1. Check if assignable. If yes;
    // 2. Get all interfaces other than the one we are looking for (T),
    // 3. And see if any of them inherits (T), and if yes, return false.
    // Please see the ! in front of obj.GetType() in the second line
    return
        typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()) &&             // Check if assignable first
        !obj.GetType().GetInterfaces()                           // Then, get all interfaces of type
            .Except(new Type[] { typeof(T) })                    // except the interface we are testing against (T)
            .Any((IType) => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(IType));  // and see if any of them inherits (T)
}
```